# Math theories in Game Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, game-theory, mathematical-modeling, algorithmic-game-theory

What are all the mathematical theories in Game Theory? I have taken Mathematical Modelling, including: application of linear systems, matrix operations, inverse of matrix, leontif input-output model, subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, Properties of determinants, complex numbers, eigenvalues and eigenvectors, characteristic equation, diagonalization. What is the next most natural step to take, in order to learn mathematical approaches to Game Theory? Since there are many applications of Game Theory, I'd like to learn as many mathematical approaches as possible.

Comment: Basic game theory doesn't need much - quite a bit can be taught with only high school math.

Comment: Min max theorem shows that any zero sum game has an optimal strategy this is proved is hinged largely that a function of a compact set always achieves inf and sup.

Comment: Also for continuous games the concept of probability density functions is used as possible strategies. In general though the harder math used in game theory is usually very specific to the instance or question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a book and start working through it. I recommend On Numbers And Games by John Conway. Like Thomas said, you don't need too much math background to understand game theory, and if you miss something you can look it up while working through a book.

Comment: I understand game theory, I would like to apply mathematics to game theory, just b/c I love math

Comment: @mel Conway's book is very mathematical, as far as I remember (it's been a few years since I read it). The point is that most game theory, even from a mathematical perspective, doesn't take very advanced mathematical techniques. Most of what you need is linear algebra and some probability theory.

Comment: txs! If you know of more updated material,I'd greatly appreciate that!

Comment: @mel While there are newer books, one of the great things about math is that old, well-written books like this one rarely become outdated :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the applications of game theory in economics then I would recommend Ken Binmore's book "Playing for Real."

By the way: every modern textbook on game theory that you pick up will be mathematical. Only the most elementary books for popular audiences are non-mathematical.

Comment: txs! def gonna check that book out!